# Ideal implementation, saving in /Documents, on the roll, or both?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface

Question about iPhone app programming. I'm storing photo's and video's in my app, which works fine. I have lines for adding it to the ~/Documents directory inside the app, and lines for adding it to the Photo Roll.

However, what is expected behaviour in the way of storing data? Do users want all stuff on the Photo Roll, or only in app, or both? Currently it's only in app, but that would prevent users from getting it out of the app. Only Photo Roll is impossible for me, since checking whether a photo is still on there is tedious. Storing on both places has the disadvantage of size. Should I pick one option, or present users a preference?

What does Apple want? I've picked up chatter about disallowing 'heavy storage' apps from the Store.

Any thought or direction is much appreciated!

Regards,

Reinder

Comment: Why would storing the images in `Documents` prevent the user from getting them? Haven't you enabled iTunes File Sharing?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm looking into it: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app If I wouldn't want to implement File Sharing, then what would be the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Which way to go might be a matter of the use case, and maybe even of taste. If you want people to easily share these images then storing them in the photo roll is probably a good option. If you think that might "pollute" or "spam" the photo roll then go for iTunes File Sharing.